# Convert non-numeric character to numeric in sas

Tags: sas

I'm trying to change a non-numeric character variable, region to a numeric. 
When I use the input function it converts all values in the character to missing. Can anyone help me and maybe explain why this happens?

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you provide a sample of the data and the code you have tried.

Comment: Are you asking to convert a character variable to a *factor* variable, like [tag:r] would?  Showing example of data and 'want' is definitely a good idea here.

Answer (score 0):

Line, you need to use an informat that fits the data. Normally, the w.d informat is used.
If, for example, you have the values in the first column and uses the 6.2 informat, you will get the values in the second column:

```
2300 23 
-2300 -23 
23. 23 
2.3 2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dummy disposable variable to load the character data, create a SAS format to translate the char value to numeric in a new persistent variable.

1. Load your data into a dummy disposable variable, dispose1.
2. Create a SAS Format with the rules to translate the characters into region numbers. ej.

   ```
   proc format library=library;
     value Num_region
     'Region 1'         = 1
     'Region 2','North' = 2
     'R3','East'        = 3
     '4','W'            = 4
     other              = 9
       ; 
    run;
   ```

   see here for more details: [Building and Using User Defined Formats](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/236-29.pdf)
3. Create a new Numeric Variable using input() function applying new format to the dummy variable

   ```
   Numeric_var = input(dummy,Num_region.);
   ```

   4. Discard dummy variable

      ```
      drop dummy;
      ```